# MYSQL LEFT JOIN to 2nd Table on last row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

we have three tables

```
1. customer 
2. custumerorder 
3. order_type
```

**customer:**
custumer_id , custumer_name, custumer_address,custumer_phone,status

**Order_type**
order_type_id,orderType,

**custumerorder**
custumerorder_id,custumer_id,order_type_id ,order_date,Total_order,shipping_info

i want to trace out the last order details
so i have query

```
SELECT c.*,
       tblcusorder.order_dt,
       tblcusorder.orderType,
       tblcusorder.shipping_info
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT max(cr.order_date) AS order_dt,
           ot.orderType,
           cr.custumer_id,
           cr.custumerorder_id,
           cr.order_type_id,
           cr.shipping_info
   FROM custumerorder cr
   INNER JOIN order_type ot ON ot.order_type_id=cr.order_type_id
   GROUP BY cr.custumer_id ) AS tblcusorder ON tblcusorder.custumer_id=c.custumer_id
WHERE c.status='TRUE'
```

**Issue**

as I am using Max() function on order date so its showing last order date which is ok, but rest of row data is not from that row (customer order) and ordertype is not link with that date .

Comment: Have you tried anything??? If tried then shows us..

Comment: I'm guessing what you meant to do was to *order* by cr.order_date desc and then grab the first.  This will grab only one row of course, but you have to decide the information you want to view.  You cannot mix and match queries with good results.  Either you want the latest order or you want all orders, but not both.